# Error using composer to install Drupal: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php, drush

I've been trying to troubleshoot this error in many ways (including re-installing composer, clearing the cache, diagnosing composer, checking for an empty AutoRun folder in the registry etc.) I've also tried installing Drush first but get the same error.

For clarity this is my first Drupal install, but I've been very careful up to this point and no warnings or errors are showing up in my php.

I've been running the following from the admin (and default) command line:
`composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev`

The full error message is as follows:

> Installing drupal-composer/drupal-project (8.x-dev 3b9ee0d3a1c9363d53fc6da4111701269496e9ca)
>     - Installing drupal-composer/drupal-project (8.x-dev 3b9ee0d)
>       Cloning 3b9ee0d3a1c9363d53fc6da4111701269496e9ca
>       Failed to download drupal-composer/drupal-project from source: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:\drupal-project,C:\drupal-project): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)
>       Now trying to download from dist
>     - Installing drupal-composer/drupal-project (8.x-dev 3b9ee0d)
>
> [UnexpectedValueException]
>   RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C://drupal-project/,C://drupal-project/):
>   The system cannot find the file s   pecified. (code: 2)

So far I haven't come across the same error posted anywhere; any help would be hugely appreciated. My next move would be to install Drupal directly from Git but I understand this is not recommended for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following command :

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev ./ --stability dev -vv
```

This can display an error token message , github have protection from web crawling, so you need to create a token on github like was indicated in message

Comment: the error I get from running this is [InvalidArgumentException]
  Project directory ./ is not empty.

Comment: i created an access token on github and added it to composer using `composer config -g github-oauth.github.com` but still got the same result

Comment: Lance you have to precise an empty directory , don't create it defore so rm drupal-project:8.x-dev before try command

Comment: composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev new-project --stability dev --no-interaction

Where new-project is the name of the folder you want to install it to. I've written up how we migrated our D8 sites to use composer here: https://medium.com/@kimbeaudin/how-we-migrated-our-drupal-8-sites-to-use-composer-in-8-steps-3b70b8087cd